# Problem with object literal - return closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, closures, object-literal

I have a module with different methods
One of the methods call other method on setTimeout and I need to pass some values to the second method which is called

first I did this

```
transitSlide: function() {
        var left = parseInt(this.$ul.first().css('left')),
        newLeft = parseInt(left) + 100 ,
        index = (newLeft / 100),
        bool = (newLeft <= (this.slideShow.length - 1) * 100); // this is always TRUE

        this.$a.removeClass();
        this.$ul.addClass('fade');

        setTimeout(this.changeSlide.bind(this), 400);


        return bool; // I need to pass newLeft variable too !!!
}

changeSlide() {
    if (this.transitSlide) {
        alert('true') // this works!
    } else {
        alert('false')
    }
}
```

but I need to pass more values then I did this

```
transitSlide: function() {
        var left = parseInt(this.$ul.first().css('left')),
        newLeft = parseInt(left) + 100 ,
        index = (newLeft / 100);

        this.$a.removeClass();
        this.$ul.addClass('fade');

        setTimeout(this.changeSlide.bind(this), 400);

        return  {
        direction: (newLeft <= (this.slideShow.length - 1) * 100) ? true : false, // this is always TRUE
        // direction: true // also doesnt work !!!
        newLeft: newLeft
        }
}

changeSlide() {
    if (this.transitSlide.direction) {
        alert('true')
    } else {
        alert('false') // this doesnt work!
    }
}
```

but it doesnt return true to the second method even when I put simply true value
then I found out I should () invoke it
then I wrote

```
transitSlide: function() {
        var left = parseInt(this.$ul.first().css('left')),
        newLeft = parseInt(left) + 100 ,
        index = (newLeft / 100);

        this.$a.removeClass();
        this.$ul.addClass('fade');

        setTimeout(this.changeSlide.bind(this), 400);

        return  {
        direction: (newLeft <= (this.slideShow.length - 1) * 100) ? true : false, // this is always TRUE
        newLeft: newLeft
        }
}

changeSlide() {
        if (this.transitSlide().direction) {
                alert('true') // this works! but setTimeout call it over and over !!!
        } else {
                alert('false')
        }
}
```

but setTimeout make it run over and over (infinitive loop)

what can I do in this situation ?
How can I pass these values and access them in second function without invoking it

Comment: There is no reason to write `? true : false`.

Comment: thats not the problem , I even removed it and simply wrote true, the problem is the function should have () invoke in the changeSlide to be able to use return properties

Comment: You are calling `transitSlide()` from the timeout callback. And you are setting the timeout in `transitSlide()`. So of course it makes a loop. It's not clear why you need to do that instead of just setting a separate method such as `this.direction()` and checking that.

Comment: Thanks, I can but the module already have too many functions, Im concerned this too much separation is not a correct way, Im not sure , also is there a way to pass these values in other methods as arguments or ,,,?

Comment: maybe you should show the code that _calls_ the first function.  Or maybe even try to explain to others what you're actually trying to do with these slides.

Comment: its actually nothing complicated , the other methods mostly reading the data from JSON , and making it ready to write in Mustache templates and binding some events to some buttons and also preparing the initial style of the elements, 
these 2 methods , there is a this.autoTimer() methods which kick this transitSlide() methods (the transit set the direction and new position value and then the changeSlide() actually doing the change and again at the end of the changeSlide() the autoTimer() will be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `apply()` method to pass both parameters and `this` keyword

```
transitSlide: function() {
    var left = parseInt(this.$ul.first().css('left')),
        newLeft = parseInt(left) + 100 ,
        index = (newLeft / 100),
        direction = (newLeft <= (this.slideShow.length - 1) * 100);


    this.$a.removeClass();
    this.$ul.addClass('fade');

    setTimeout(this.changeSlide.apply(this, [direction, newLeft]), 400);

},

changeSlide(direction, newLeft) {
    if (direction) {
        alert(true)
    } else {
        alert(false)
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Function return values aren't stored anywhere; they're just returned to the caller.

It sounds like you actually want to pass that state to the second function as a parameter when you call it using `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(() => otherFunction(parameters))
```

Comment: appreciate your answer, Im trying to pass these 2 variables (newLeft, and a boolean value which indicates the direction) from transitSlide() method to the changeSlide() method

Comment: You can pass two parameters exactly the same way you pass one parameter.

Comment: you mean return something; return another; in the next line instead of object literal

Comment: No; I mean pass parameters, not return a value.

Comment: would you please show me an example or a link to this method

Comment: now I got this error -------------->  Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined after invoking the function the bind(this) doesnt work, now I should find a way to move 'this' to the new function

Comment: You don't need `bind()`.  Learn about arrow functions and how `this` works.

Comment: thank you, I found this one works : 
setTimeout(this.changeSlide.bind(this).call(direction, newLeft), 400);
first binding to pass 'this'  and then running then calling and invoking function with call method, Im reading about arrow functions too,

Comment: That does not work; it calls it immediately.  You need to pass a function.

Comment: it seems there is no other way except I define this.setDirection() and this.setNewLeft() function and call them ,

Comment: and Im trying to avoid ES6 to fully understand old methods and ways of writing javascript first

Comment: Then you need to pass a function expression and use `.bind()`: `function() { use this }.bind(this)`